# Unable to access shared drive in windows XP Pro/Home from Windows 7 Pro 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, network-shares

We have shared drives in Windows 7 pro and Windows XP Pro/Home. We were able to access XP shared files and Windows 7 shared files previously. Now we are able to access only shared folders shared in XP. When we try to access Windows 7 files from Windows XP it says "Access denied", but I am able to access public folder of Windows 7 from all the systems. I Googled and tried all the possible steps but none of the solutions worked for me.

For better understanding of my problem

```
1. Windows XP (shared files)        -> Win7  - sharing fine
2. Windows 7  (shared drive/folder) -> WinXP - access denied
3. Windows 7  (public folder)       -> WinXP - sharing fine
4. Windows 7  (shared drive/folder) -> Win7  - sharing fine
5. Windows XP (shared files)        -> WinXP - sharing fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set both the sharing and the security.

So, for example, set sharing to Everyone with full control, then in the same properties window, click the Security tab and add everyone with full permissions.

As per your comment make sure it is not your AV or firewall

Comment: ya i have set full control an permission is given to everyone...even then issue is the same..previously the sharing was working fine...the issue started recently

Comment: Can you try to totally disable all anti virus and all firewall.

Comment: ya now it worked it was the avast which was blocking and too many permissions.....thank you

Comment: This resolved it. Was having problem in security permission.

Answer (score 1):

it was the problem with too many permissions blocking the share and 3rd party antivirus/firewall...

i solved the issue by giving only one permission "every one"---full control and changed the antivirus

thanks for all the support